# Why is onDrop event automatically re-rendering everything?

Tags: reactjs

It seems that 'onDrop' event is forcing an update on the components.
I want to control the changes and updates myself.

The drop event updates state data in an asynchronously because there's some lazy loading involved.
When all changes are made I wish to explicitly call onChanged callback on parent but by then an unnecessary re-rendering was already performed.

Is there a way to prevent this automatic re-rendering?

wouldn't shouldComponentUpdate require some king of hacky 'isDroping' flag in state?
Otherwise it would just be diffing the data wouldn't it? Isn't that what an update really does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shouldComponentUpdate](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to control whether your component re-renders; this *will* require maintaining internal state/logic around your dragging, it may be necessary depending on your situation.

With that said, it sounds like there may be something else going on in your code. If there really is no difference in the data being rendered, React should be smart enough to not re-render.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the 'shouldComponentUpdate' strategy. I updated the question to address this confusion.

Comment: @RuiFortes I've updated my answer slightly. It'd be very helpful to have an isolated example in a JSBin because I suspect that there may be something else going on here that is causing react to re-render.

Comment: you're rigth...I forgot to stopPropagation 'dragEnd' event

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I forgot to stopPropagation on another (dragEnd) event